# What is the probability of the generated sequence by random.sample in python being repeated?

Tags: python, random, probability

I use the following code snippet to generate the random characters

```
char_set = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
Randomno=''.join(random.sample(char_set*10,9))
```

Comment: If you run it enough times, 100%

Comment: @NickA that depends on how you look at it, any sequence, yes, if it is one particular sequence, then it is never quite 100%.

Comment: @LSelter well true, it *approaches* 100%

Answer (score 3):

The total number of unique values should be 62^9 (1.3537087e+16)

Number of symbols ^ length.

"Used for random sampling without replacement" so my previous maths was incorrect as characters cannot repeat in a given sample.

The chances of matching any sequence is 100% after 62^9 runs, the chances of matching a specific sequence tends towards, but never reaches 100% as the number of runs increases, as you are never guaranteed to to get any particular sequence.

*Adding my thoughts from the comments:*

random uses the marsenne twister: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister,  which according to its wiki page is quite robust. http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html according to the docs random should not be used for cryptographic purposes. This makes sense as MT is completely deterministic and given the initial parameters and see the same sequence can be reproduced.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, yes.
However I was interested in looking at it from the python perspective.
Here, I multiply the number of symbols by 10 so we get 620 ^ 9 = 13537086546263552000000000 before a number repeats. But will random.sample actually generate all these possible combinations?

Comment: random uses the marsenne twister: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister 
which according to its wiki page is quite robust.
https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html
according to the docs should not be used for cryptographic purposes

Comment: @LSelter: I think this comment is in fact more relevant for OP than answer you gave.

Comment: @Shre1407: I think you could ask for more details about Mersenne Twister algorithm on [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @running.t Thanks! will do

Comment: @Shre1407 Mersenne Twister has quite a large period: `2**19937-1`. For best results, you should seed it with lots of entropy. As L Selter said, you should _not_ use Mersenne Twister for cryptographic purposes: it's fine if you're doing non-crypto stuff like Monte Carlo simulation, but definitely don't use it for making passwords!

Comment: @PM2Ring does random.sample internally use an OS specific seed? https://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r32/Lib/random.py

Comment: @Shre1407 to quote wikipedia: only if....
"Multiple Mersenne Twister instances that differ only in seed value (but not other parameters) are not generally appropriate for Monte-Carlo simulations that require independent random number generators, though there exists a method for choosing multiple sets of parameter values."

Comment: @PM2Ring to quote your link: "None or no argument seeds from current time or from an operating system specific randomness source if available."

Comment: Yes, `random.seed(None)` will use a system source of entropy if available, which it should be on most modern computers, but on some systems, eg embedded systems, it will fall back to system time. I'm not sure how many bits of system entropy it uses though, my guess is that it's at least 512. When you provide your own seed, in the form of an str, bytes, bytearray, the seed you supply is extended by its SHA-512 hash, as you can see in the [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L97).